# Buffering with Scanner upon System.in in Java

Tags: java, console, io-buffering

I have a problem with Scanner in Java. I have a method parsing `System.in` and creating an object bases on this data. But if I create `Scanner` inside the method, I have 2 ways to do that, i.e. with closing and without. In the first case, `Scanner.close()` closes `System.in` too, otherwise it buffers in advance and the characters it has buffered become unreachable from another Scanner. 
So that now I pass a `Scanner` instance into method. But it can't be reliable if you need to read from console another object e.g. via `BufferedReader`. In addition, it seems not to be a really clean design solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the design has considered that only one `Reader` or `Scanner` can actually read the `InputStream` (`System.in`) at a time, so having several `Reader`s on it is useless (as it consumes the stream as well) thus making it feasible to close the underlying `InputStream`.

Edit:
One solution is to use `InputStream` directly (`read()`) and handle the reading of bytes yourself. For example `String` has the constructor `String(byte[])` that you can use together with `substring()` to only return the parts that weren't used.

Comment: Reader and Scanner aren't supposed to read the stream simultaneously but sequentially. And the reader an implementation is a detail and shoul be hidden in the implementation. Not to call close() faces us with another problem.

Comment: For example you pass InputStream into your method and create an instance of Scanner. But imagine you've fed the console 10 lines of text when 5 lines are sufficient to read the object properly. But when creating a new Scanner happens again the latter 5 lines aren't reachable just because the former Scanner buffered them too. And if even during destruction Scanner returns buffered lines to InputSteam, one can't rely on GC

Answer (score 0):

Define a `BufferedReader` and pass it to your methods. Use it to read lines into a String and attach a `Scanner` to it instead of `System.in`.

Comment: The same problem occurs. If closing, stream closes too. If not, data buffered in Scanner doesn't return to the Reader

Comment: You're using the `Scanner(String source)` constructor?

Comment: i use Scanner(System.in) because i can't predict how many symbols i shoul read